# Problem using NSXMLParser with NOAA data on iPhone

Tags: iphone, xml, parsing, noaa

Can anyone help me see why NSXMLParser is not causing these methods

```
parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:
parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:
```

to fire for the  part of the following data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:NDFDgenResponse xmlns:ns1=""><dwmlOut xsi:type="xsd:string"><?xml version="1.0"?>
<dwml version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.nws.noaa.gov/forecasts/xml/DWMLgen/schema/DWML.xsd">
```

(body excluded)

```
</dwml>
</dwmlOut></ns1:NDFDgenResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I'm not an XML expert, but to me, the `<dwml></dwml>` part looks like just a regular element, to be parsed just like the parts before it.

I *do* get two parser:parseErrorOccurred: errors, #200 and #201, but they occur during the parsing of the  `<SOAP-ENV:Body>` element, not the `<dwml>` element, so I'm not sure if they are relevant.  Thanks for any help you can give me.

Update: A friend of mine has told me offline of several errors in the data above.  I can't understand why NOAA would be sending out malformed XML though -- is there some secret to parsing it?

Comment: Is it perhaps because you have two `<?xml?>` tags there?

Comment: huh -- good point.  I'm not familiar with the ?-prefaced style tags.  Should the ? even be there?

Comment: Oh, btw a quick note: That's not MY xml -- that's what comes down from the NOAA SOAP service.  Just in case that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is a SOAP web service, you might want to try this: http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/

Comment: The problem is not getting the data from NOAA, it's parsing the XML using the iPhone's NSXMLParser class.  Can you help me with that?